# How to prove $\cos ^6x+3\cos ^2x\space \sin ^2x+\sin ^6x=1$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove the following equation.

> \begin{eqnarray}
> \\\cos ^6x+3\cos ^2x\space \sin ^2x+\sin ^6x=1\\
> \end{eqnarray}

I can't prove it by many methods I use.

Please give me some hints.

---

***Thank you for your attention***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems one sign in your equality is wrong. One actually has
\begin{align}
1=\left(\cos^2x+\sin^2x\right)^3&=\cos^6x+3\cos^4x\sin^2x+3\cos^2x\sin^4x+\sin^6x=\\
&=\cos^6x+3\sin^2x\cos^2x\underbrace{\left(\cos^2x+\sin^2x\right)}_{=1}+\sin^6x=\\
&=\cos^6x+3\sin^2x\cos^2x+\sin^6x.
\end{align}

Comment: That was fast! Saw there was an issue, but you nailed it! +1

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$\sin^6x+\cos^6x=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^3-3\sin^2x\cos^2x(\sin^2x+cos^2x)$

Can you continue?

Comment: @O.L. no problem, sir.

Answer (score 2):

It’s false as stated: try it with $x=\frac{\pi}4$. The middle sign is wrong. If you subsitute $u=\cos^2x$ and change the middle sign, it becomes

$$u^3+3u(1-u)+(1-u)^3=1\;,$$

which is easily verified.

Comment: Today is the big day!

Answer (score 2):

I'll start from your left hand side instead of R.H.S.

All terms contain integer powers of $\sin^2x$ and $\cos^2x$. Rewrite the l.h.s to

$$(\sin^2 x)^3+3(\sin^2x)(\cos^2 x)+(\cos^2x)^3$$

Cubic? It feels like $(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$ but notice the lack of $a^2b$ and $ab^2$. To make up for the missing powers, I'm tempted to tweak the L.H.S by introducing a harmless multiplier $1=\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x$:

> $$ \begin{align}
>    L.H.S.&=(\sin^2 x)^3+3(\sin^2x)(\cos^2 x)\cdot1+(\cos^2x)^3\\
>          &=(\sin^2 x)^3+3(\sin^2x)(\cos^2 x)\cdot(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)+(\cos^2x)^3\\
>          &=\quad ?\quad \text{(Try to expand)}   \\
>          &=(\sin^2 x + \cos^2x)^3=1
>       \end{align} $$

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach

From algebra we know
if $a+b+c=0$ then $ a^3+b^3+c^3 = 3.a.b.c$

> $$Derivative \begin{cases}a+b+c = 0  & \text{(1)}\\ \Rightarrow a+b=-c \\ \Rightarrow (a+b)^3=(-c)^3 & \text{cubing both sides} \\ \Rightarrow a^3+b^3+3a^2b+3ab^2=(-c)^3 \\ \Rightarrow a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)=(-c)^3 & \text{but }a+b = -c\text{ from (1)} \\ \Rightarrow a^3+b^3-3abc=-c^3  \\ \Rightarrow a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc & \text{ subtracting } c^3 \text{from  both sides} \end{cases}$$

Now if $a=cos^2x$, $b=sin^2x$ and $c = -1$, we have
$$a+b+c=cos^2x + sin^2x - 1 = 0$$

thus we have
$$\Rightarrow (cos^2x)^3 + (sin^2x)^3 +(-1)^3 - 3 \cos ^2x .\sin ^2x . (-1) = 0 $$

$$\Rightarrow\cos ^6x+3\cos ^2x\space \sin ^2x+\sin ^6x=1$$

Hence Provded

Comment: Nice method~!!but why $a^3+b^3+c^3 = 3abc$ if  $a+b+c=0$? Are there any references?

Comment: @CasperLi: I thought it was well known identity. For a proof I have added a spoiler

Comment: Nice~! Thank you. It is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Expand $(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)^3$ and apply Pythagorean theorem.