# If $a^3 + b^3 +3ab = 1$, find $a+b$

Tags: contest-math, factoring

> Given that the real numbers $a,b$ satisfy $a^3 + b^3 +3ab = 1$, find $a+b$.

I tried to factorize it but unable to do it.

Comment: What I try first is
$$
(a+b)^3 = a^3 + b^3 + 3ab(a+b) 
$$
... and maybe you can somehow manipulate this to find the answer

Comment: So first, write
$$
a^3 +b^3 = (a+b)^3 - 3ab(a+b)
$$
and then,  from the given equation, you know that $a^3 +b^3 = 1- 3ab$ ...

Comment: Why not just write the answer @MattiP.?

Comment: @PeterForeman I don't still have the full solution; I'm just dotting down my own thoughts here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a continuum of solutions to
$$
a^3+b^3+3ab=1
$$
Suppose that
$$
x=a+b
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
1
&=a^3+(x-a)^3+3a(x-a)\\
&=x^3-3ax^2+3a^2x+3ax-3a^2
\end{align}
$$
which means
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=(x-1)\left(x^2+(1-3a)x+3a^2+1\right)
\end{align}
$$
So either $x=1$ irregardless of $a$, or
$$
x=\frac{3a-1\pm(a+1)\sqrt{-3}}{2}
$$
Thus, other than $x=1$, the only real $x$ is $-2$, which comes from $a=-1$.

That is, the only two real values of $a+b$ are $1$ and $-2$.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** \begin{align} x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz& =(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz) \\ &=(x+y+z)\left(\frac{(x-y)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2}{2}\right) \end{align}

**Solution:**
$$0=a^3+b^3+(-1)^3-3(a)(b)(-1)=(a+b-1)\left(\frac{(a-b)^2+(a+1)^2+(b+1)^2}{2}\right)$$
so $a+b=1$ or $a=b=-1$. The latter gives $a+b=-2$.

Comment: afterthat what to do?

Comment: @mathslover Ok, well I have added the solution...

Answer (score 2):

Using the formula $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$ and denoting $(a+b)$ by $A$, we have (from the assumption)
\begin{align*}
&a^3+b^3+3ab=1\\
&(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)+3ab=1\\
&A(A^2-3ab)+3ab=1\\
&(A^3-1)-3abA+3ab=0\\
&(A-1)(A^2+A+1)-3ab(A-1)=0\\
&(A-1)(A^2+A+1-3ab)=0,\\
\end{align*}
where we use the identities $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab=A^2-2ab$ and $A^3-1=(A-1)(A^2-A+1)$.

Therefore, $A=1$ or $A^2+A+1-3ab=0$. 
In the latter case, replacing $A$ by $a+b$, we can conclude that the only solution is $a=b=-1$ (getting $a^2+(1-b)a+(b^2+b+1)=0$ and using the determinant for real solutions of quadratic equations), which is left to you.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3=a^3+3ab(a+b)+b^3$$

Or see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539953/how-to-prove-cos-6x3-cos-2x-space-sin-2x-sin-6x-1), especially my answer to it.

Comment: ya i had already reached there how to solfe afterwards.?

Comment: @mathslover: That gets you one solution by inspection: what value must $a+b$ have in order for the righthand side of my equation to be equal to $a^3+b^3+3ab$? Then you need only show that no other solution is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The three solutions of the equation $a^3+b^3+3ab=1$ are

$$b_1=1-a,$$
$$b_2,b_3 = \frac{1}{2}\left(a-1\pm i\sqrt{3}(1+a)\right).$$

If $a\neq -1$, since $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, we must have $a+b=a+b_1=1$. If 
$a=-1$, then the imaginary part of $b_2,b_3$ vanishes and we find two solutions for $(a,b)$: $(-1,-1)$ and $(-1,2)$ so $a+b$ is -2 or 1 respectively.

Comment: How about $a=b=-1$

Comment: $a=b=-1$ works, and gives $a+b=-2$

Comment: Thank you, I was assuming $a>0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

> $$
> \pars{a + b}^{3} = a^{3} + 3a^{2}b + 3ab^{2} + b^{3} = 1 - 3ab + 3a^{2}b + 3ab^{2}
> =
> 1 + 3ab\pars{-1 + a + b}
> $$
> $$
> x^{3} -3abx + 3ab - 1 = 0\quad\mbox{where}\quad x \equiv a + b
> $$
>
> $$
> \pars{x - 1}\pars{x^{2} + x + 1} - 3ab\pars{x - 1} = 0
> $$
> One solution is $\color{#ff0000}{\large x = a + b = 1}$.

When $x \not=1$ $\pars{~a + b \not= 1~}$:
$$\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
0 = x^{2} + x + \pars{1 - 3ab} = x^{2} + x + 1 - 3a\pars{x - a}
=
x^{2} + \pars{1 - 3a}x + \pars{1 + 3a^{2}} = 0
\tag{1}
$$
This equation discriminant $\Delta$ is given by:
$$
\Delta = \pars{1 - 3a}^{2} - 4\pars{1 + 3a^{2}}
=
-3a^{2} - 6a - 3 = -3\pars{a + 1}^{2} \leq 0
$$

Since $x = \pars{a + b} \in {\mathbb R}$, this analysis doesn't yield any other solution when $a \not= -1$. When $a = -1$, Eq. $\pars{1}$ has the double root
$x_{\pm} = \pars{3a - 1}/2 = -2$. Then,

> $$
> \mbox{the solutions are}\quad
> {\large\left\lbrace%
> \begin{array}{rcl}
> a + b & = & \phantom{-}1
> \\[1mm]
> \mbox{and}\quad a + b & = & -2  \quad\mbox{when}\quad a = -1
> \end{array}\right.} 
> $$

Comment: One *important* idea to take from this answer is introducing the new variable $x$ for what you are trying to find, and rewriting the problem in terms of $x$: in this case, using $x=a+b$ to eliminate $b$.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks. It was crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$a^3+b^3+3ab=(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)+3ab\ldots\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

As stated, there is no unique answer.

Let x = a + b, c = 3ab. Then

a³ + b³ + 3ab(a + b) = (a + b)³, i.e.

1 = a³ + b³ + 3ab = (a + b)³ - 3ab(a + b - 1), i.e.

x³ - cx + c - 1 = 0, i.e.

(x - 1)(x² + x - c + 1) = 0, i.e.

x = 1 or x = ½ [± √(4c - 3) - 1], if c ≥ ¾.

Answer (score -6):

$$a^3+b^3-1+3ab=(a+b)^3-1-3a^2b-3ab^2+3ab=$$
$$=(a+b-1)((a+b)^2+a+b+1)-3ab(a+b-1)=$$
$$=(a+b-1)(a^2+b^2-ab+a+b+1).$$
Thus, $$a+b=1$$ or
$$a^2+b^2-ab+a+b+1=0$$ or
$$(a-b)^2+(a+1)^2+(b+1)^2=0,$$ which gives $a=b=-1$ and $$a+b=-2.$$

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you do it?

Comment: How did you write: $$"a^2+b^2-ab+a+b+1=0$$ or
$$(a-b)^2+(a+1)^2+(b+1)^2=0"$$ This is not true right ?

Comment: It should be $$(a-b)^2+(a+1)(b+1)=0$$ I think.